# youtube data api v3 search with hashtags

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

It seems https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search with the query parameter as a literal hashtag value does not return the same result as the UI (youtube.com) does.
The search results are however similar if the '#' is removed.
Is this intended behavior or a bug in the API?

Also, if we hit search/list without `order` parameter, we do get results. Otherwise not.

Comment: Why would you be searching for hashtags in the first place? Hashtags are a fragment identifier in a URI; they indicate which HTML element to show when the page is loaded.

Comment: @ObsidianAge This is not the tag used as anchors. This is abut the YouTube data api and its parameters.